# send email subscribe with php connect with third party smtp

Tags: php, email, sendmail

i run php to send email list using third party smtp. I want to show Receipt(TO:) with my customer email. So i need to loop call php email function follow:

```
$emailList = explode("\n",file_get_contents('/list1.txt'));

foreach ($emailList as &$value) {

    $email = new Email();
    $email->setFrom("info@xxx.net");
    $email->setToList($value);
    $email->setSubject("360’s Got Talent");
    $email->setHtmlContent($str);

    $apiClient = new ApiClient("edm@xxx.net", "xxx");

    $response = $turboApiClient->sendEmail($email);

    var_dump($response);

    echo ":: $value has been sent.<br />";
}
unset($value);
```

Is it standard way to do ? 
Are there anyway to sent one time but can show TO: one by one ?

because when I run this, PHP is waiting total process and then writing report (echo). Sometime server is showing 504 Gateway Timeout.

or Can I make PHP run one by one ? report every line once it done, not waiting the whole process like a batch process.

Please guide.